# Need to read a file and use results as command line arguments in a shell scrip

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following output file from a venn program.

```
[1, 2],106
[1, 3],2556
[2, 3],5207
[1, 2, 3],232
[2],7566
[3],8840
[1],5320
```

I need a command to get each line result number as variable argument in a script like this:

$area1=here it must come the results after [1],
$area2=here it must come the results after [2],
$area3=here it must come the results after [3],
$n12=here it must come the results after [1, 2],
$n13=here it must come the results after [1, 3],
$n23=here it must come the results after [2, 3],
$n123=here it must come the results after [1, 2, 3],

## these results will then be used in the script below to draw a venn diagram.

```
cat << catfile >> $prefix1-VennDiagram.R
library(VennDiagram);
venn.diagram(
    x = list(
        "$sample1" = c(1:$area1, $(($area1+1)):$(($area1+$n12)), $(($area1+$n12+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123)), $(($area1+$n12+$n123+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13))),
        "$sample2" = c($(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2)), $(($area1+1)):$(($area1+$n12)), $(($area1+$n12+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123)), $(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2+$n23))),
        "$sample3" = c($(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2+$n23+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2+$n23+$area3)),  $(($area1+$n12+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123)), $(($area1+$n12+$n123+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13)), $(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2+$n23)))
        ),
    filename = "$prefix1-VennDiagram.tiff",
    col = "transparent",
    fill = c("red", "blue", "green"),
    alpha = 0.5,
    label.col = c("darkred", "white", "darkblue", "white", "white", "white", "darkgreen"),
    cex = 2.5,
    fontfamily = "arial",
    fontface = "bold",
    cat.default.pos = "text",
    cat.col = c("darkred", "darkblue", "darkgreen"),
    cat.cex = 2.0,
    cat.fontfamily = "arial",
    cat.fontface = "italic",
    cat.dist = c(0.06, 0.06, 0.03),
    cat.pos = 0
    );
catfile

Rscript $prefix1-VennDiagram.R
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner:

```
sed 's/^.*\],/ /' yourfile|tr -d '\n'|sed -e '$a\'
```

If you are passing this thing as options to a command you may remove the last `sed` and use

```
sed 's/^.*\],/ /' yourfile|tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Great! It worked nicely... and if I want to designate a variable value for each of the line number? How should I do? Ex. this is my result [1, 2],106
[1, 3],2556
[2, 3],5207 and now I want that: [1, 2],=$area1 ($area1 should be the 106 value) [1, 3],=$area2 (2556) etc

Comment: Sorry to say that but I don't quite understand your question. I suggest that you edit the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` to print the last comma-separated field of each line, and then (provided the argument list does not exceed its limits) `xargs` to assemble them into a single line:

```
$ awk -F, '{print $NF}' yourfile | xargs
106 2556 5207 232 7566 8840 5320
```

Comment: Great! It worked nicely... and if I want to designate a variable value for each of the line number? How should I do? Ex. this is my result [1, 2],106
[1, 3],2556
[2, 3],5207 and now I want that: [1, 2],=$area1 ($area1 should be the 106 value) [1, 3],=$area2 (2556) etc